# Are questions about the development status of third-party programs on-topic?

Tags: discussion

The title probably isn't the best summary of my question, so don't let it hold too much weight.

Recently, this question about whether or not Krusader was still being developed was asked:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/779668/is-krusader-still-being-developed

Krusader is a file manager designed for KDE, but the description also says it works on pretty much any UNIX-based system that has a GUI.

Now, I've never actually seen a question here asking about what happened to some third-party software, so I don't really have an experienced option on this. The Help Center says questions on the development of Ubuntu are on-topic, but I don't think that applies to Krusader, since it isn't Ubuntu.

I actually can't seem to find anything on questions asking for news about third-party Linux applications, either for or against them being welcome, so I'm a little confused; it seems to just not be something that's been covered.

I, personally, don't think this question is on-topic, as it isn't asking about how to run Krusader on Ubuntu, which would be on-topic. Instead, it's specifically asking about only Krusader (the question doesn't even mention Ubuntu: if it still works; how one might install it; etc).

To me, that's an instant indication that it's off-topic. In my opinion, from what I've seen on this site, if the question doesn't even seem to involve Ubuntu, then it's off-topic.

I know for sure I've missed some of my arguments and opinions, but they'll probably come up later, when I don't need them :p.

Is this question off-topic? Is it on-topic? I VTC'ed it, but it seems at least one person disagrees with my decision.

## P.S. (?):

This question is not asking what [this one](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14382/asking-questions-about-third-party-applications-running-on-ubuntu) is. That's asking about usage of third-party programs. I'm asking about asking about development of third-party packages. (That's not a repetition, just terrible phrasing.)

Comment: I wouldn't say it is off-topic, but I don't think it is something we can objectively answer.. necessarily. It's a gray area, I guess.

Comment: I with @Seth here, and I'd even venture to say that since we can't really answer it, it is technically off-topic.

Comment: Similar type of question that I'd asked long ago: http://askubuntu.com/q/544927/158442 It came close to being closed, but remained open, largely because of Sylvain's definitive answer, I guess.